# Auto-disputing of "unclear" flags

Tags: feature-request, flags, vote-to-close

Today I witnessed some strange behavior, where a [question belonging to a new user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30571147/change-both-line-style-and-color-for-each-plot-automatically) was put on hold as "unclear", based seemingly on its *pre*-edit version.

I humbly think that the question, after [my total edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/30571147/revisions) (which was largely based on the OP's clarifications in the comments), is perfectly acceptable on SO.

Chronologically speaking, this is what happened:

1. User posts a question.
2. Question gets *flagged* as unclear.
3. An edit to the question is made by somebody other than the OP.
4. A moderator sees that the question was flagged a bunch of times and puts it on hold w/o giving it much thought (?).

The way I see it, following **step 3**, existing "unclear" flags should have become disputed.

In light of this I would like to put forward a motion that either:

1. Auto-dispute of "unclear" question flags takes place if a certain percentage of characters was changed in the questions, or
2. Show some notice to mods that a post was modified from the time the first flags were received (so as to somewhat reduce "manual auto-approval" of flags).

Comment: I have reopen votes, but I don't intend to cast them here.  The question still does not have the code the OP tried, so we'd just end up re-closing it with a slightly different reason.

Comment: @Kevin - Your comment is valid generally, but I respectfully disagree with it in this case. Obviously I'm not forcing anybody to use any votes. I do not know what your background in MATLAB is, but I can tell you that the mention of `hold` and the description of its behavior **is** the "tried so far" part of the question. As a relatively experienced MATLAB coder, I can also say that the question, in its current form, may be useful to many people - including myself - which is why I bother with it so much.

Comment: That's not code.  If someone linked to a function in (say) Python's standard library docs and asked how it worked in a given situation, I would want to see the actual code they wrote, not just their description of that code.  Does MATLAB not have code?

Comment: @Kevin - It actually is code. In MATLAB, the command `hold` alone opens a new figure/axes/plot and sets it's default behavior to what is quoted from the documentation of `hold`. The question itself deals with modifying this default behavior. You could obviously say that "hey but then you end up with an empty plot - so you didn't reproduce the problem", to which I say - while true, adding some random plots is about as complicated as defining a new tuple in Python...

Comment: So you're saying there's an MVCE in that question?  One I can paste directly into MATLAB and run with absolutely no modification whatsoever?  If not, then IMHO there is no code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Most* edits to questions that merit closure aren't complete overhauls of the question that completely fix the problems it has and turn it into a great question.  Automatically disputing all close flags/votes after every edit would be completely unwarranted.  If the edit truly has made the post acceptable, it generally shouldn't get closed by future voters, in the rare event that it does, it can be reopened.

Comment: I see. The question was edited since it is clearly not a bug.

Comment: @Dev-iL I consider this to already be an answer to the feature request to make it behave as you want.

Comment: And I see your point, however I'm not talking about "_Automatically disputing all close flags/votes after __every__ edit_" - hence the suggestion of the percentage of change, which may be regarded as "_complete overhauls_".

Comment: @Dev-iL Character count is simply not a strong indicator of whether or not an edit has truly fixed all of the problems with a question.  For example, taking non-code and marking it as code is often a very significant edit, as far as the diff algorithm is concerned, but that's not going to make an unclear question clearer.  The same would apply to rearranging the contents order, or applying other types of appropriate formatting.  At the end of the day, you're just not going to have any good heuristics, you need human eyes to see if it was really improved, and the current system does that.

Comment: And yet, those very same human eye you just mentioned are the ones who put on hold a perfectly good question. I am more concerned with the human-error aspect of the moderator in this case - maybe a notice for moderators is required stating that the post was edited since the first flags arrived...?

Comment: @Dev-iL There's no way that moderators would be able to review every single such case.  As I said, it's fairly rare for a question to be closed if it was edited such that it really did fix all of the problems, and in those rare cases, the question can simply be reopened.  One edge case doesn't mean the whole system needs to be revamped.

Answer (score 1):

Many years later, it appears that SO decided to [introduce a similar feature](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394871/3372061), specifically:

> **3. Automatic Reopening**
>
> When a user edits a hidden question in a substantial way, it will automatically reopen (unhide) the question and return to its pre-close, public state. Additionally, a question can only be automatically reopened once. Any subsequent reopens would require review through the reopen queue.