# Option to hide deleted posts

Tags: feature-request

I want to have an option in StackOverflow / SE user interface to hide deleted answers. In some cases I see a lot of deleted answers (marked red) and they are usually placed between answers that were not removed. Please, add an option to either hide deleted answers or put them at the bottom so that they are not mixed up with other answers.

Comment: *"they are usually placed between answers that were not removed"* That is odd. Make sure that your sort order is by votes.

Comment: @CodyGray I do not want to sort posts by votes. I want to hide posts that were removed.

Comment: *"...or put them at the bottom so that they are not mixed up with other answers."*

Comment: Maybe the target question should get the tag [meta-tag:status-review]?

Comment: I categorically oppose the hiding of deleted posts from users with moderation privileges, so I don't think it needs to be reviewed or revisited, @Dharman.

Comment: @CodyGray I do not want to hide them permanently. Just put them at the bottom of the page and ideally collapsed on load. I still want to be able to see them if needed, but they should not be as prominent.

Comment: @CodyGray I want to opt out of seeing those deleted answers. SE/SO devs could put a button or checkbox or whatever that will help to hide them. Hide them *temporarily*.

Comment: e.g. here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php 28/113 are not deleted and the page loads extemely slow, because all answers are loaded. Maybe the deleted ones could be lazy-loaded

Comment: If this is just for yourself, then it's easily accomplished by adding the CSS: `.answer.deleted-answer {display: none;}`

Comment: Some good numbers are needed for this FR - I (as I suspect a large majority of users) use "by votes" view and yet to see a case where deleted answers consistently show up next to top rated answers. As result I don't see any value in this request for me.