# Why does this question lack focus?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions, reopen-closed, needs-more-focus

This question of mine:

[Generating a single include file from a hierarchy of includes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63070627/generating-a-single-include-file-from-a-hierarchy-of-includes)

got closed for lack of focus. I don't understand why. The problem is very clearly defined IMHO. I already got one answer that - while only partially helpful - had no trouble targeting the exact problem. (And I already have another, more useful answer which I'd like to post.)

If whoever closed the answer would have commented about what needs more focus, I could have obliged...

Comment: it's also borderline asking for recommendations.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: I was actually hoping there was some kind of trick involving preprocessor invocation; and was also expecting perhaps a suggestion that I use libclang; etc. Also, if somebody would have closed for that reason, I would have at least known what they thought was wrong with the question.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre - If someone has been coding C++ for decades, and they have a recommendation for solving this problem, that is exactly what the site was designed for.

Comment: It looks like a question that would have been asked within the first month of Stack Overflow's existence (nearly 12 years ago). Are you sure there isn't a duplicate somewhere?

Comment: @PeterMortensen: You'd be surprised how questions I've asked which you would think already had dupes :-)  ... I haven't found a dupe yet. But it could very well exist, I suppose.

Comment: @oguzismail - Not sure I follow. Why do you think that the question is asking for a recommendation of software to use?

Comment: It's not a software recommendation question. That some people answer it with links to software might hint that it may be too broad to answer completely here.  In that case maybe there are interesting sub-questions hidden. I'm fine with the dupe target from 2011,except that the accepted answer misses the point.

Comment: @Trilarion: Yes, I didn't like the accepted answer there either, so it was a bit painful to mark my question as a dupe :-(

Comment: I think what muddies the water a little is that right off the bat you state that CMake isn't critical. That sets the tone for what is a very open problem domain and a question which reads to be very broad. And I don't even think it is relevant to really mention CMake several times, because what you seem to be looking for is a way that fits into an automated build process to get your desired result; a merged header file without duplication. Tool, script, code, magic spell, whatever. If it can be executed, it's good. I think the non-committed phrasing of the question led to crossed wires.

Answer (score 8):

We need more questions from experts like yourself, and we need more content like the type being produced in such a question.

While uninformed "I've heard from my neighbor's friend" guesses are surely not the goal for content, highly informed "I've been doing this for 20 years and here is the best way I've seen it done after trying hundreds of approaches" content *is what we need*. That type of content is what drives the success of this site, and historically what made Stack Overflow what it is today.

Using "lacks focus" or "opinion based" to close questions which would clearly benefit from decades of experience is counter productive.

I have previously wrote in depth on the [subject of question closure in general](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/396018/1026459)

> The strict interpretation of lacks focus and opinion-based flies directly in the face of the intent of the site. Subjective questions are perhaps some of the most important material on the site, and they are being actively prevented - we literally have subject matter experts twiddling their thumbs now, just look at the decrease in answering rates from the top users.

Your question here just highlights the exact point I am making. While we do need ways to prevent people from just asking for someone to do all the work, we also need to ensure that experts can coordinate with each other on subjects which leverage industry leader's insights.

Comment: +1 I have just recently started being more active in attempting to answer questions, even though I've had an account for a long time, but this specific issue here is the reason i did so. It seems like so many of the moderators on here are more interested in the quality of the content, than actually helping people. It's almost like they have never had to support a user who didn't know how to articulate their problem.

Comment: @Jason "...are more interested in the quality of the content, than actually helping people."  Yeah.  That's *literally* the point of the site.

Comment: The two are not mutually exclusive. I am not really suggesting that we need to drop quality to help people. I am suggesting that shutting down high quality posts under the guise that they need professional expertise is counter productive.

Comment: The about page says "More than 50 million unique visitors come to Stack Overflow each month to help solve coding problems ...". I agree with Travis, the two are not mutually exclusive. People can be assisted in the process of making content better too, but that's not what I have seen happen. It's more likely that issues will be closed and deleted out of hand with little explanation or assistance.

Comment: We need closure, and we need deletion. The amount of material that needs removal is still very high and very present. Curators also don't have the time to sit down and individually explain to each user what went wrong with their question. There is a vast amount of documentation in place for those explanations if that is what someone wants when their post is closed and or deleted. What I am saying here is that, the system itself is tuned wrong in this one aspect, and that we need to evaluate changing it to improve the overall ability for subject matter experts to produce higher quality content.

Comment: @fbueckert: I'd rephrase your first comment here: "It seems the moderators are more interested in penalizing posters of imperfect questions than in trying to get those questions improved to the point of acceptability, and finally answered to help the poster."

Comment: @TravisJ: Partially agree. We do need closure, but we also do need curators to write clear reasons for closure; and in many cases - guide the poster w.r.t. how to improve their question.