# What to do when same user has many closed questions?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, question-quality, specific-user

I came across a new contributor that has been a member for about one week. During that time they have asked three questions. One was closed for not meeting the [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions), the second has two close votes and the most recent question has been closed as a duplicate. By the way, I also voted to close it as a duplicate.

Shouldn't there be some way of helping this member to learn how to properly use Stack Overflow?

Yes, you point that person to the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and to the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) as well as to ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) but the person continues to ask questions that show no research effort.

I did search for "user many closed questions" but did not see anything that gave me the impression that this question has already been asked.

The impression I get regarding the questions posted by the member that I described above, is that they are intentionally and stubbornly refusing to make an effort to search for an answer to their question prior to posting it.

What can be done if it is obvious that a member intentionally continues to post duplicate questions? In other words, they give the impression that they have no intention of using Stack Overflow correctly.

Comment: Yes, but you can't unless you reach out to them. And some users don't want help to improve their Questions, they just want answers, and will abandon their own posts once they get those in either Answers or in comments.

Comment: The user interface tries to help new users when writing their Questions, which in my opinion should be very helpful to them. The help center contains a lot of information about how to go about asking Questions, but I find it to be in lack of a good overview, and it's pretty endless once a user decides to click the links. They may even find themselves on meta, which is an endless abyss of links. I've heard rumours that the process/help will be improved, but I've yet to see what the actual plan is. I made a "rant" once [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/394890)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's not really anything specific that you or anyone else needs to do. The close reasons are all designed to give specific feedback, so hopefully users who were unable to learn from the general information in the Help Center will be able to learn from the specific cases of having their question(s) closed.

If you really feel that a moderator needs to reach out to the user and offer guidance, then you can raise a custom moderator flag on one of their posts. Be sure to explain the situation clearly (e.g., *"This is a new user who has asked 3 questions, all of which have been closed as unsuitable for this site."*) and make a specific request (e.g., *"Please reach out to this user and offer some guidance about the site rules."*). There is a standard moderator message template for this, and we will generally be happy to send it. But we won't hold out much hope of it solving the problem, and neither should you, since it's essentially just a recapitulation of what is already in the Help Center, and clearly that didn't work the first time around.

Some people just learn better from the School of Hard Knocks. Do your part by voting to close the questions as appropriate. If you feel so compelled, you can also leave specific guidance in the comments underneath each question (but don't comment unless you can add something that the close reason doesn't already say).