# Should the Help Centre link to specific Meta questions that provide additional context and clarity on the rules?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, meta, help-center

I got to reading the Help Centre today, in particular [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions), and was once again horrified by how little information users are given there in order to ask good questions.

In particular, while the "needs details or clarity" close reason [is applied for questions containing images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question), there is zero mention of this in the so-called Help Centre.

While Stack Exchange Inc. has consistently refused to update the Help Centre to make it actually helpful, would they perhaps be willing to consider adding links to Meta questions that cover some of the topics in more detail? In this case, the [aforelinked Meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question).

Comment: The Help Center page about [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) mentions "DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc...". The problem with the help center and links to meta posts is the overwhelming amount of information one need to go through to get an idea of what is required/expected of users. On top of that, lots of users have opinions about the rules and close vote according to their opinion, which is not always what's in the information in the help center (or meta)

Comment: I've said it before: It would be helpful to have an end-to-end user manual for Stack Overflow, that doesn't turn into an abyss of meta posts with links in a never ending spiral.

Comment: *I got to reading the Help Centre today* ... never too late ...

Comment: @Scratte well, if it was just one meta ....

Comment: I don't like how the "help" for a user is a big dump of a lot of things that *might* be wrong without clear indication of *what* is wrong. If the problem is mentioned in the article at all. [I wish there was a standardised way to provide clear, actionable steps to improve a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/394874/).

Comment: I wish help center will be updated regularly, trigger can be a big enough discussion with concensus. Even more crazy idea: if community will maintain help center content, similar to "documentation" attempt we had some years ago.

Comment: @Scratte The corporation's whole Q&A site model works on a disorganized non-committal evolutionary antidocumentationarianistic FAQy webby searchy Metanical Turk that isn't broke $o don't fix it. Although once in long while a meta post does get FAQed into a help center.

Comment: @philipxy What?

Comment: @Teemu The company doesn't seem to want to have too many things written down in the official help place (it's a relatively lean document for such a complex organization). They kind of rely on meta (which can be like a jungle) to sort problems out. Maybe they simply don't want to maintain a larger document, maybe they don't want to commit to too many details. In any case the question would be which meta questions exactly to link to.

Comment: @Trilarion That's pretty much what I managed to parse from philipxy's comment, I couldn't figure out the exact meaning of "_antidocumentationarianistic_", though.

Comment: @Teemu It's a pun on "antidisestablishmentarianistic" as in [antidisestablishmentarianism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antidisestablishmentarianism_(word)). Per the comment's (juxta)posing sloppy crowdsourced FAQing-up vs organized centralized prescriptivity not just syntactically, via multisyllabic stuffiness, but semantically, via--well--metaphoric [antidisestablishmentarianism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antidisestablishmentarianism). (Note that the word, as distinct from the concept, has its own Wikipedia article. Which, I guess not absurdly, I expected.)

Comment: @philipxy Thanks, I think I understand now = ). Unfortunately I'm missing a lot of fun here on Meta because of my limited English skills. At the end, the problem is, that we've too much rules. Years ago I participated a chat forum (not a Q&A), the only rule was: "Don't be a fool here", and that kinda worked.

Comment: @Teemu That wouldn't work here with millions of users. The "you're a fool" close reason would be misused quickly. Surely you can have too many rules but that is not the problem here. The problem is that the help center is too small and meta is a jungle and both aren't connected enough and operated by different entities.

Comment: @Trilarion What would the ideal form of the Help Center be? I imagine the model of a community-moderated selection of documents wouldn't be any less of a mess than Documentation was.

Comment: @ZevSpitz That's a good question and I'm not sure at all. Ideally, the help center would be comprehensive, but not lengthy, would give solid information, be consistent but still allow for an evolution over time, while being easy to maintain. Maybe it should even map the ambiguity that is present in meta (you can definitely find answers that contradict each other and are all upvoted). The consensus on meta is not really the score and many discussions aren't really leading to actionable outcomes. We have the FAQ as a meta structure of meta.

Comment: @ZevSpitz They say you cannot learn to program from reading on main SO alone because there is not enough meta structure in the pile of Q&A. In the same way you cannot learn how to use SO by reading on meta SO alone because there is not enough meta structure on meta and the gap between the pile of Q&A in meta and the help center is too large.

Comment: @Trilarion Do you think it possible to distill down to some core principles? For example, "no images of code" -> easier to copy/paste -> easier to reproduce -> easier to answer; and "no images of code" -> better SEO on the text -> easier to find. What might those core principles look like, and how could they be determined?

Comment: @ZevSpitz That's kinda the ideal - instead of walls of text, just a simple list of "do"s and "don't"s with a very short "why" next to each. It's been proposed before but, like pretty much every good proposal Meta has put forward for actually making SO more usable to newbies, was ignored. Meanwhile far more complex things, that nobody actually wants, are implemented. It really gives one the impression that SE Inc. isn't managed, so much as it is staffed by people who just work on pet projects.

Comment: @ZevSpitz One thing that worked well here is tagging. Tagging is used to indicate that a post is in the hot meta posts list, tagging is also used to indicate the status of a feature-request. We could use tagging to associate a question with a certain help center page, something like "help-center-how-to-answer" and then this question could be listed as additional reading (associated resource) below the help center article. That would make it dynamic. Now there is a tag limit. Maybe these special tags should not count towards the tag limit.

Comment: Relevant MSE posts: [What parts of the help center can site moderators edit?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/259914/335251), [Is the Help Center content identical on all sites in the Stack Exchange network?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/331026/335251) In particular, the CMs try to avoid customizing help center pages on individual sites, because then those pages are no longer in sync with the network-wide version of that page – meaning that to keep the site-specific override of the page up to date, any changes to the network-wide version have to be manually copied over.

Comment: That said, for proposed changes to the help center that apply networkwide, [you can make a suggestion on MSE and tag it with the \[help-center-proposed\] tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/help-center-proposed).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I think that it should, given that the help center pages themselves are updated with a low frequency. A community defined section with a title like "Additional relevant articles on meta" at the bottom of each page would be great. It would help closing the gap between the official help center and meta, while being rather non-intrusive and also clearly delimited from the rest of the help center.

And for the decision of which questions to link to which help center pages, I propose to use the tag system. We use it for defining the Hot Meta Posts candidates and to set the status of feature-requests and there is a lot of infrastructure already available. We could have an initial discussion "Which meta Q&A should be linked to which help center pages" (maybe even split by help center pages) and then moderators would set the appropriate tags (like "help-center-how-to-answer" to indicate a Q&A should be linked from the "How to answer" page in the Help center) and the tag setting would be recorded in the post history and could be undone. This would allow to dynamically evolve this list of linked Q&A in a transparent way and with moderator oversight.

But any other system would be fine too. In general this is a good idea. Given the past track record, chances for implementation of this idea for a significant number of linked Q&A are rather low though (0.6%-0.8% approximately).