# Do we need to be nicer to new users?

Tags: discussion, downvotes

I know this question has been asked [before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9953/could-we-please-be-a-bit-nicer-to-new-users), but I think it needs to be asked again since it is an ongoing effort to have a changing community finding the [right balance](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/219662/in-response-to-the-lets-be-nicer-to-new-users-people-in-general-threads-i).

Today a new user on Stack Overflow asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66541959/c-how-can-i-get-this-output) containing an expected output, a piece of code and actual output. In other words, a legitimate question which more or less complies with the [Stack Overflow guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), but with an answer that is probably too simple and specific to be usable for anyone but the OP.

This new user got at the time of writing 9 downvotes without a single one bothering to leave a comment explaining the reason for the downvote. This is an efficient method to scare off new users.

Clearly, one can imagine cases where users are spamming the site with nonsense and they need to be told that in unambiguous terms, but I think it happens far too often that such hard ammunition is aimed at users with good intentions who are more in need of kind advice.

In my opinion, the current culture on Stack Overflow is too excluding and occasionally arrogant in general and particularly towards new users.

So the question is: Am I right in this opinion and if so, where, and how could we change this culture?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What about the community is "toxic" to new users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/342779/what-about-the-community-is-toxic-to-new-users)

Comment: The user didn't get downvotes, the post did.

Comment: If people's expectations of "being nice" is to help every new user out with their personal problems regardless of how the question is phrased, then it's those expectations that need to be readjusted.

Comment: That comment in the linked question was also unwarranted, especially the part  _"It would be nice if downvoters explained the reason, but I suppose sometimes people are just in a bad mood"_. Leaving any feedback alongside a downvote is not mandatory (don't shame those who do it either), and you should not be giving the idea that downvotes are just made out of spite.

Comment: I believe this to be a duplicate of [What really amounts to "be nice to new contributors"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379704/what-really-amounts-to-be-nice-to-new-contributors)

Comment: That post, that you've linked to, looks like something treating [so] like it's a free coding service; I'm not surprised it got so many downvotes. SO is *not* a free coding service. Code Dumping, and effectively "Fix my code", is not a helpful question; it's not even a question.

Comment: this is a somple debug it yourself question. and should be closed as such

Comment: There's a warning in comment box `"...is a new contributor. Be nice"`. But I think it was most because the question was poorly formatted (someone added it later) without any explanation of the problem.

Comment: You say that the question "more or less complies with the StackOverflow guidelines" but the very article you link says that *the problem has to be explained*. We have some program, some wrong output and some expected output. No explanation what the program should do. We're expected to reverse-engineer it based on the expected output (and who knows if that is even possible - I've seen impossible expectations). There is an entire headline called **Introduce the problem before you post any code** and I don't see that in the post. The title is a perfect match for the **Bad** example of titles.

Comment: @suriyel And that is a fair point to make and perhaps cast a downvote, but I would say that if I bother to cast a downvote I should also write a comment saying that the question is poorly formatted. Otherwise, I should just ignore it. The downvote by itself is not constructive.

Comment: @neilsen it is very constructive - it stops other people from opening a question that their time is not well spent on

Comment: The downvote by itself _is_ relevant. It's a signal of quality on a post. A question or answer with a score of -1 is definitely perceived differently from one with a score of 0. It may not give much to the author of the post, but that is not the main purpose of the vote anyway. So no, ignoring a post is no better than downvoting it if merited. This isn't the first this is brought up. Please read [the faq on mandatory feedback alongside votes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/357436) and [this FAQ proposal on why downvoting is important to the site](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/405699).

Comment: Oh..THAT question.  I noticed it earlier.  It had a vague, near-useless title and two blocks of char dumps with no immediate clue as to why they existed, why they were different or how they were related to the code supplied.  I VTC as 'Needs details'.  I did not bother to downvote it - after VTC, I had wasted enough time on it already.

Comment: see also: [When is Stack Overflow going to stop demonizing the quality-concerned users who have made the site a success?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/366858/839601)

Comment: *"In other words, a legitimate question which more or less complies with the StackOverflow guidelines, but with an answer that is probably too simple and specific to be usable for anyone but the OP."*, in essence, the user asked a valid, legitimate question... that isn't useful. What are downvotes for?

Answer (score 29):

> Do we need to be nicer to new users?

No, new users could be a bit more thoughtful towards us.

> Today a new user on StackOverflow asked a question containing an expected output, a piece of code and actual output. In other words, a legitimate question which more or less complies with the StackOverflow guidelines,

No, it did not comply with [guidelines](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648). Where is the error? Where is the description of what currently happens? Where is the debug attempt / results?

> This new user got at the time of writing 9 downvotes without a single one bothering to leave a comment explaining the reason for the downvote.

The post got downvotes, not the user. Please stop with the argument that downvotes are aimed at the user. You don't use the same argument for upvotes, right?

That question got all kind of comments pointing out the trivial mistake. So now it is not only enough to leave a helpful comment but you have to be explicit why you downvoted a post?

> This is an efficient method to scare off new users.

That might be so but I see it as an efficient way to scare of posts that won't be useful for future readers. Yes, that means this user might get trapped in the quality algorithm sooner or later but having less low-quality posts is so much more valuable then having a relentless stream of sub-par content.

> Am I right in this opinion and if so, where and how could we change this culture?

Yes, you're right with your opinion. I suggest we start changing the culture at the start / on-boarding of new users to make explicit that asking here and getting an answer is not a human right. If we can change the culture of new users so they make it their habit to contribute the same high quality content that lead them to this site in the first place, we wouldn't have so much contention between the existing experts that share their knowledge for free and the visitors that want to benefit from it.

If you're not yet at the quality level required by Stack Overflow, practice at Quora, Reddit or other traditional forums.

Comment: It is a fair answer. Not the one I hoped for, but there is no point in asking a question if one does not want to hear the answer. Not surprisingly I disagree in most of your points. It is a bit difficult to argue in the comment format, but this sentence "Please stop with the argument that downvotes are aimed at the user" summarizes what I think is wrong. Why should I stop the argument? It is my opinion. Am I not allowed to express it just because you disagree? Should the site be cleansed of opinions not shared by the majority? In any case, thank you for the answer, I respect your opinion.

Comment: @nielsen why do you think downvotes are aimed at users? So long as one side says they aren't and one side says they are, we aren't getting anywhere. At least the side of downvotes on content can point to to documentation and policy on the intended use.

Comment: Annacdotal evidence, but at least personally, the usercard is the UI element I look at least. How can I be voting on the user rather than content if I haven't read who the user is until after voting?

Comment: @user1937198 I do not know the intention of the voter, but I am quite sure that a new user is likely to perceive unexplained downvotes as a signal that the user is not welcome. I do not think everyone downvoting need to explain the reason, but I think especially towards new users, an explanation should be made if it is not already present in the comments.

Comment: @nielsen Providing a suggestion to the user that the votes were based on *"bad moods"* (as you did)  and not about the poor content quality is totally counterproductive to trying to help that user though. Same goes for your comment to the user that there is nothing wrong with their question when it clearly does not meet site guidelines which is what prompted the votes in the first place

Comment: @nielsen Not all users are new. There are some with 1 reputation who don't participate, but rather comment on posts. Now, checking out a user's profile to see if they're new or not is a complete waste of time. Reading the rules and asking good quality questions is, IMO, a better option for new users.

Comment: "*No, new users could be a bit more thoughtful towards us.*" I'd say "yes". We can always be nicer. But the rest of the sentence remains relevant. Courtesy is not a one-way street.

Comment: We need more and  better management of bad questions, not less.  It would help if more users got effectively involved with curation - some users have an up/down vote ratio of infinity, and that is not good for site quality:(

Comment: @nielsen  what I don't understand is this. If a user read through https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask why are they surprised downvotes are cast on their question? That page is linked from the /ask "wizard". So it is totally fine to skip all that and then wait for someone to spoon-feed guidance that they should have consumed themselves 6 to 8 hours earlier. We have created http://idownvotedbecau.se/ which we can't fully leverage because new users are offended by that as well. We can't do one-on-one mentoring. We tried, it didn't scale.

Comment: @charlietfl You may be right, but my focus was concern about another new user being mobbed. The question may need a little words about what is the problem in the observed output, but otherwise it is a clear an answerable question. If someone (my self included) would not bother to post an answer, ok, but if anyone wants to contribute by helping a novice, it is fine by me.

Comment: I'm not a mob! Stop insulting me and my fellow curators.

Comment: @VLAZ yes or no, enough is enough. There seems to be no limit on how courteous I need to be.

Comment: In which case reading through https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357436/why-isnt-providing-feedback-mandatory-on-downvotes-and-why-are-ideas-suggestin to understand the impact of what you are talking about on the stack overflow culture is a good start. But remember, at over 12,000 questions a day, there is a limited attention budget per question.

Comment: Is it time for another pagefull of rude/abusive questions from new use....accounts?

Comment: @MartinJames - Yes; I think we need the 3 page treatment just to illustrate how rude and abusive some users are to the community

Comment: @MartinJames this seems to be a bi-weekly routine, last time it was [Is downvoting harmful and should it be removed completely?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/405582/839601) _Downvote exorcists_ probably believe that repeating it with this frequency will somehow make it go away

Comment: Assuming your last sentence is serious, I can't say I agree with that. Given how different the format, and culture is on Quora and Reddit (from what I understand of how they operate), practicing asking questions there is unlikely to help when it comes to asking on SO.

Comment: *"Why should I stop the argument? It is my opinion."* It's not an opinion, your understanding, @nielsen , is wrong. Me stating "Grass is Purple" isn't an opinion; is simply wrong. Votes have **never** been about the user, you can see that simply by [hovering over](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYeNn.gif) said vote options with your cursor. *"This **question** shows"* ***not*** "This User". If votes were about users, they would be on the User profile page, not the question.

Comment: @Larnu Maybe I have expressed my opinion badly. I am not talking about the definition of a vote, nor the intention of the voter, I am talking about the perception of the receiver. I could edit the post, but somehow I am more inclined to delete it entirely. Should I?

Comment: You can't delete the question. Somehow my answer got an upvote and that blocks your delete option.

Comment: @nielsen you are not the first to talk about the perception of the receiver so editing the question won't make it any less of a duplicate. If you want to write a new meta post, I suggest you do a meta site search for the word "toxic" to get a long list of notes of what not to do :)

Comment: @Gimby Thanks. Among the many things I have learned from raising this question is how many possible duplicates I missed in my first search. Probably as my first popular comment today I can say that I do not intend to write new meta posts in any foreseeable future.

Comment: @nielsen maybe you can chat with Scratte: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405828/should-the-help-centre-link-to-specific-meta-questions-that-provide-additional-c#comment829973_405828 as he shares your concern and has ideas about better guiding new users so they either understand up-front what a downvote means or even prevent them from getting downvotes. Not easy to solve but if more users of the community can get behind that it might fly. I'm sure there is a chatroom where you can find him (and maybe others that have similar opinions).

Comment: The solution is to create a special SO for beginners/learners, like [English Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @suriyel I'm not sure if the experts you need will go to such site. That is not a unique idea. That has been proposed more then once in the past. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50409/propose-newbie-overflow-site-or-section and direct links: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/50409?lq=1

Comment: @rene thanks for the links, you're right but I still like the idea.

Comment: @rene Some see the knee-taking  grovelling subservience as 'courteous', others as 'look how stupid the naive nerds are, doing all that obvious homework for the street-wise con artists!  I'll get them to do my work too, since I'm way smarter than they are!' (Yes, you know this, but I had to say it:)

Comment: @suriyel I think the idea is good. SO is clearly not for learners and it would be better to come clean and direct learners to another site instead of having these ongoing conflicts about how to treat learners. I think there would be a group of experts (including myself) who would be willing to help under the right circumstances. A lose thought: maybe reputation could be shared between the sites.

Comment: @nielsen I would not go near such a site.  Just one problem with so-called 'learners' is that some are totally incompetent and have designed/written/built/tested/debugged nothing.  When you ask them to print out some value as a debug aid, they don't know how to do it because they are clueless scammers, taking money to get assignments done and merely reposting to SO.

Comment: @MartinJames I somehow guessed that already :-). Not everyone enjoys teaching, but there are frauds everywhere, even among high-rep SO experts. It does not imply everyone are frauds, not among learners nor among experts. That being said you are right that the ratio of frauds is likely higher at the learner level. A "learner site" would have to address that (which is partly what I meant by being willing to help under "the right circumstances" - I may not have high SO-rep, but with 35 years of SW development experience, I dare to consider myself an expert in some areas).