# How is this JavaScript question opinion based?

Tags: discussion

My question https://stackoverflow.com/q/70055226/3198356

[image]

was closed as opinion-based.

The [help link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) states that

> It’s often possible to rewrite opinion-based questions to focus on a more fact-based line of questioning.

OK, I said near the beginning of the question that

> I am of the opinion that if you can do what you need server side, why use client side scripting?

but, that is to frame the question, and not the question being asked. The actual question (stated in the title of my question and outlined fully within the rest of the post) states facts backed with links which is also showing that I am researching my question and not just asking for opinion.

So, why is this question closed as opinion based?

Comment: I agree with you, that the question shouldn't have been closed as "opinion-based". Rather, it looks like it should have been closed for being "too broad".

Comment: ^ To elaborate on that, you basically asked _"What's the point of JavaScript"_... That's not a suitable question for SO.

Comment: Also, you may want to beware of the [Meta Effect](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235225/what-is-the-meta-effect) where asking a question on meta about a stackoverflow question brings additional attention to the question, possibly positive attention and possibly negative attention.

Comment: [Image for people without 10k rep](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugCIO.png)

Comment: The comment on my question from @Ivar was very helpful and I am thankful for that. The comment highlighted some reasons why my question was naive to say the least and has made me see that there are some possibilities where JavaScript may be needed.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: Please switch to default color scheme when posting screenshots of SO content. The huge black blob in the center of the question is very distracting and barely readable.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels there is no close reason for "too broad" anymore though, so I guess close voters picked what closest matched :( "Needs more focus" is not a drop-in replacement since it has that weird focus on asking multiple questions.

Comment: @ChrisRogers referring to your closed your question, you can also not use PHP but use something like Python. So what can PHP do that Python cannot do? Or .NET? Or Java? Or whatever technology someone else might favor but you do not? It's a discussion that can go nowhere pleasant or productive, so I would not hold it with anyone but people you know and respect.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The question is arguably opinion-based and arguably not opinion-based, but either way it's definitely not a suitable question for Stack Overflow. The main problem is that you're asking a very broad question which has so many different valid answers that there is no hope of a definitive, comprehensive answer. So if the question was not closed as "opinion-based", it should definitely be closed as "needs more focus". Please don't worry too much about the exact close reason.

So, I would favour closing it as "needs more focus", but with that said here are some reasons people might see your question as opinion-based:

- Regardless of the exact wording of your question, it's clear that your motivation for asking the question is that what you really want to know is, *"why should I learn JavaScript?"*. It's a matter of opinion whether you should or shouldn't, let alone what is a good or bad reason for learning or not learning JavaScript.
- Implicit in the question *"what can I do with JavaScript that I can't do with ..."* is that you are asking for examples of things which are *worth* doing. For example, JavaScript can be used to show a modal dialog box with some text and an 'OK' button (using the `alert` function), but whether or not that would be a good answer to the question depends on your opinion. If you don't care about being able to show modal dialog boxes, then this would not be a satisfactory answer.
- Implicit in the question is also that you're asking for examples of things which *should* be done with JavaScript as opposed to pure HTML/CSS. In principle, it might *technically* be possible to achieve something like a modal dialog box without JavaScript (e.g. by having an element which covers the screen and prevents mouse interactions, but which gets set to `display: none` when it has the `:active` pseudo-class due to being clicked on). That would be a *terrible* way of doing it, so probably "modal dialog boxes" should be a valid answer, but only because of the opinion that the non-JavaScript solution *should not* be used.

Comment: Wanted to write an answer to a similar effect but you were faster. The only think I wanted to cover in addition is that the question is too broad *in addition* because a lot of it seems to apply generally about [rich internet applications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_web_application) not specifically JS. Flash and Silverlight were also used for RIAs. True, those technologies were phased out largely in favour of JS but it's still not a purely JS question IMO.

Comment: this is probably related: [Gorilla vs. Shark](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/)

Answer (score 1):

The close reasons need a lot of work, but since there is huge turnover in the moderator and community manager position, it never gets done.

I think the appropriate close reason for this question was Vague AF<sup>1</sup>, but still, there is no place for "what can JavaScript do that PHP along with HTML5 and CSS3 cannot do" at Stack Overflow.

This question should have been answered through your own research.

<sub>1. if you want to know how I really feel, try here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/396018/1026459</sub>